# Modify HTML document using PHP or something

Tags: php, html

Let's say I have this document:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <p id="change"></p>

    </body>
</html>
```

And then I have this other document.

```
<html>
    <body>
    <input type="text" name="message">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </body>
</html>
```

And I want to change the `<p>` of the first document with the text you input in the second document. How can this be done?

Comment: What do you mean change <p> with the text you input? Do you mean that when you enter text in document 2 this text should inserted in document 1 between p#id?

Comment: yes and stay like that, but I know I have to use mySQL for that :/

Answer (score 2):

**First document:**

```
<html>
    <body>
    <p id="change"><?php echo(htmlentities($_POST['message'])); ?></p>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Second document:**

```
<html>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="first_document.php">
       <input type="text" name="message">
       <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Change "first_document.php" to match whatever the actual filename of your first document is.

**How it works:**

The second document sets up a html form whose contents are posted to the first document (via a HTTP POST).  The first document then takes the 'message' parameter from the post data, sanitizes it via htmlentities to prevent cross site scripting attacks, and outputs it onto the page.

Comment: But if I want the first document to stay like that, should I use mySql?

Comment: You have to modify the first document in some way because at the moment it doesn't accept any input.  Even if you used MySql you would have to modify the first document.

Comment: I mean, for a comment section for example, I would have to upload the comment to mySql, and then get it and post it in the `<p>`? After that, would the comment stay forever in there?

Comment: It doesn't generally work like that.  Generally, webpages are built every time the user requests them.  This means that if you are using a database, that database is queried every time someone requests that page, and the information that is returned by the database is echo'd onto the page every time.

Comment: so every time a user gets in the section comments, the page get the comment from the database and displays it? Cool, thanks for the answer!